# tumblr custom content per tagged category

Tags: html, tumblr

With tumblr, I need to add custom title and description meta tags on tagged category pages.

such as `url.com/tagged/lifestyle` needs different title/description than `url.com/tagged/history`

Does anyone know a block level conditional for this, or a way to make custom templates for each tagged category?

Comment: Do you want this for SEO purposes? I will post an answer below, but it will not satisfy SEO indexing.

Answer (score 0):

I can manipulate the title using a hack via jQuery, but this will only run on page load.

```
//Add an id to the title tag:
<title id="chTitle">Tumblr Blog</title>


// get the current page url
$href =             document.location.href;
$primaryDir =       document.location.pathname.split("/")[1];
$secondaryDir =     document.location.pathname.split("/")[2];

if($secondaryDir == 'lifestyle') {
    $('#chTitle').text('Lifestyle');
}else if($secondaryDir == 'history') {
    $('#chTitle').text('History');
}else{
    $('#chTitle').text('Title Default');
}
```

You could actually just take the secondary directory and pass it as a variable into the page title.

```
 $('#chTitle').text($secondaryDir);
```

But you would need a default fallback for pages with no secondary dir. blog.tumblr.com/submit etc.

Comment: thanks for giving it a shot, unfortunately it is for SEO. I'd like the values changed in the source-view.